# TCL_LIBRARY in cx_freeze

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, cx-freeze

i am trying to build an exe file from my python script using the cx_freeze library. this is my code:

```
import easygui
easygui.ynbox('Shall I continue?', 'Title', ('Yes', 'No'))
```

and this is my setup code:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("tkinterVid28.py", base=base, icon="clienticon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "SeaofBTC-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["easygui","matplotlib"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Sea of BTC trading application",
    executables = executables
    )
```

and then i get this error:

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 485, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 463, in _LoadModule
    self._RunHook("load", module.name, module)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 536, in _RunHook
    method(self, *args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 613, in load_tkinter
    tclSourceDir = os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'
```

Answer (score 1):

Easygui uses some Tkinter so when compiling it you must include the Tkinter libraries.

this should just be a question of using the `include_files` arguement

Add the following arguments to your script:

```
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

files = {"include_files": ["<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], , "clienticon.ico" ], "packages": ["easygui","matplotlib"]}
```

next alter:

```
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["easygui","matplotlib"]}},
```

to:

```
options = {"build_exe": files},
```

and everything should work.  Your script should now look like this:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

files = {"include_files": ["<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter", "easygui","matplotlib"]}


base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("tkinterVid28.py", base=base, 
icon="clienticon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "SeaofBTC-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": files},
    version = "0.01",
description = "Sea of BTC trading application",
executables = executables
)
```

There is another error in your script as well.  Because you did not use `include_files` argument to include the icon you want to use.  It would not appear in the executable icon or in the output (if you used it in your tkinterVid28.py file) this would generate an error.

Oh and unless you have a reason to do so I cannot see why you imported matplotlib.  Cx_Freeze detects imports in the script you are trying to convert to an executable and not in the setup script itself but it is always a good idea to list them in packages.

I hope this sorted your problem