# How include modules - cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a file that uses the `random` modules how do I include that module in my `setup.py` file?

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['sys'], 'excludes': ['tkinter'],
                      'includes': ['random']}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(name = 'name',
      verison = '0.1',
      description = 'description',
      options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable('fileName.py', base = base)])
```

> My Script

```
import random
choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
i = randome.randint(0, 2)
title = input('Rock, Paper, Scissor\nPress Enter to continue...')
instructions = input('Please read the instructions carefully...')
end = input('Please type \'done\' to end the game...')
enjoy = input('Enjoy!')
done = False
while not done:
    You = input('\nRock, paper, or scissors? \n')
    Computer = choices[i]
    if You == Computer:
        print('Tie')
    if You == 'rock' and Computer == 'paper':
        print('Computer wins!')
    if You == 'paper' and Computer == 'scissors':
        print('Computer wins!')
    if You == 'scissors' and Computer == 'rock':
        print('Computer wins!')
    if Computer == 'rock' and You == 'paper':
        print('You win')
    if Computer == 'paper' and You == 'scissors':
        print('You win')
    if Computer == 'scissors' and You = 'rock':
        print('You win')
    if You == 'done':
        exit()
```

Comment: We it looks like you have already included it.  Have you tried it at least? If so what errors did you get?

Comment: I tried it, but when I opened the exe file, it just says AttributeError

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention.  Could you provide the script you are trying to convert as well?

Comment: I added te script.

Comment: Super.  Thank you I will now work on an answer.  (If someone else doesn't do one first.)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: I'll get it on here as soon as possible.  Sorry about the wait but I am afk at the moment.

Comment: It’s okay, post it when you got it all done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through both scripts you provided and there are a number of errors that I found they may be typing errors/ genuine mistakes I don't know but they would stop your script from working correctly.

- `if Computer == 'scissors' and You = 'rock':` should be `and You == 'rock':` (two equals signs)
- `i = randome.randint(0, 2)` should be `i = random.randint(0, 2)` (no e at the end of `random`)

Now for the setup script.

`verison = '0.1',` should be `version = '0.1',`  (version not verison)

The error you are getting occurs because you are attempting to hide the console when no GUI is present.

```
base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
   base = 'Win32GUI'
```

`base = None` would mean that the console appears.
`base = 'Win32GUI'` means that the console is hidden.  You cannot do this because there is no GUI (such as Tkinter) to work with it.

To fix this problem just remove:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
   base = 'Win32GUI'
```

from your script.

If you do this you do not need `import sys` either.

Comment: @Aidan L If you need any further help (or it doesn't work) please don't hesitate to ask me for help.

Comment: @AidanL.  To be honest I did not know this either until I tried an old script, then I realized it we both learnt something today.  Happy to help : )

Comment: Simon, I have good news and bad news. First, the good news, IT WORKS, I TRIED OUT THE SCRIPT AND IT WORKS. Second, the bad news, when I open the exe file, it instantly closes. I opened it with the cmd, that works, but by itself, it didn't. I could use some help

Comment: Right now, I am just adding an input at the end to stall the user for a random input to exit the application.

Comment: @AidanL.  There is nothing that can be done about that using cx_Freeze. If you try you script with the interpreter it will do that anyway.  Adding `input()` at the end of each `if` statement is fine (that's what I always do -many others do as well) or use a GUI (something like Tkinter).  If you are worried about the end user just put text with the input for example `input('Press any button to continue or enter "done" to exit.')`.

Comment: @AidanL. No wait.  You must have an error somewhere.  Your script should not close until you type "done".  Try launching your app from cmd and see if it generates errors.  If not try recompiling and see if any errors or warnings appears there (just because it makes an app it does not mean that the app will work).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, I not using the script above, I just made a simple program that prints out a random between 0 to 1. (So I can test whether cx_Freeze works or not, I didn’t want to create or revise long lines of code in order for me to test it with cx_Freeze)

Comment: But now I have another problem. I tried freezing my GUI program created with Tkinter. I included tkinter in the “packages” and “include” (I didn’t at “exclude since I don’t have anything to exclude) Everything was fine, but I build my setup, a couple of errors come.

Comment: I did put a “Press any key to exit...”), and it works, so I just going to stick with it.

Comment: @Aidan L.  Sorry afk again. I'll get you some links (and help with Tkinter) later.

Comment: @AidanL.  First the input problem.  There is another solution apart from the `input()` at the end of the line (not sure how useful it is) you can also use batch script.  A script that would stop the console closing (Windows only) would be `@echo off`, `call <your app name>`, `pause`.  save it in a a file with something with `.bat` extension and double click bat file to launch.  Oh if you do. However it works under Windows ONLY is that it has loads of advantages.  Changing color of text/console, setting title just to name a few.

Comment: @AidanL.  Do you get the `KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'` error?  If not what are you getting?

Comment: No, it’s something like can not find module tkinter or import error

Comment: @AidanL. [You need `os.environ` to get all the Tkinter runtimes and libraries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401552/tcl-library-in-cx-freeze/45426617#45426617)

Comment: So I import is, and then?

Comment: @AidanL. Basically Tkinter has DLL Tk and Tcl plus a load of libraries for some (odd) reason it never seems to include those libraries so you must include them manually.

Comment: @AidanL.  I'll see what else I can find.

Comment: So i import os, and then I link the tkinter or tkinter library, if the library , what is the path?

Comment: @AidanL. Do you know where you installed Python?  Generally `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>\tcl/tk8.6` for Tk and `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>\tcl/tcl8.6` for Tcl

Comment: @AidanL.  Find you Python location then it is always `\tcl/tk8.6` and `\tcl/tcl8.6`

Comment: @AidanL.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980781/problems-with-python-file-py-to-executable-exe-with-cx-freeze/47004528#47004528) might be more helpful.

Comment: @AidanL.  I did a really bad job where clarity is concerned -sorry.  It is there somewhere

Comment: Thank you, I check it later.

Comment: @AidanL. OK then.

Comment: I created a new file that just opens the `Tk()` window. Then I created a setup.py file and build it. All the extra files from the `tcllib` were imported. I ran the exe file, but it said `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: @AidanL. What does your setup script look like now (could you paste it below)?

Comment: Oh, I just import tkinter `from tkinter import *`, then I assigned the variable `master` with the value: `Tk()`. I then add a `mainloop()` at the end of the code. That's it.

Comment: @AidanL. I changed [this answer try it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401552/tcl-library-in-cx-freeze/45426617#45426617) I'll work on a working script in the meantime

Comment: I am suppose to copy the `files` variable onto my `setup.py` file?

Comment: @AidanL.  Sorry I'm afk most of today so I can't get you a script working but I'll give you some background info so you may be able solve it yourself.  The error is occurring because the tk and tcl DLL at are missing they need to be included along with your exe in the same folder (they are located in DLLs if you try and copy them manually.  The folders tcl8.6 and tk8.6 need including as well (they are located in tcl).  You can try and copy them manually see what happens but doing it the proper way would certainly be better.

Comment: So I use os.environ and add the both DLLs?

Comment: @AidanL.  Yep. Or do it manually. -I'll get an example working within the next few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This script will include everything but folders `tcl8.6` and `tk8.6`.  You will need to copy those with your build folder manually.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

files = {"include_files": ["<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter"]}

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "<Path to Python>/Python36-32/tcl/tk8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "<Path To Python>/Python36-32/tcl/tk8.6"

base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "Name of app",
    version = "0.1",
    author = "The author",
    options = {'build_exe': files},
    description = "Enter Description Here",
    executables = [Executable("tk_ex.py", base=base)])
```

EDIT:

This script works without copying and pasting anything.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
files = {"include_files": ["<Location to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Location to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter"]}

setup(
name = "Name of app",
version = "0.1",
author = "The author",
options = {'build_exe': files},
description = "Enter Description Here",
executables = [Executable("tk_ex.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: @Aidan L.  Please take a look at the above.

Comment: @AidanL.  Right I found out how to do it.

Comment: @AidanL.  Ok.  I don't know any other ways to do it so all I can suggest is 
 a "hack".  Build you exe as you did before (so you get the import error) go to the location where Python is installed.  Go in `DLLs` folder and copy `tcl86t.dll` and `tk86t.dll` to the location where your exe is located.  Next copy `tk8.6` and `tcl8.6` folders (located in `tcl`) to the location where your exe is and try again and see if it works.

Comment: @AidanL.  If this, the previous answers and the answer above does not work could you please copy the entire error message and I will see what I can do.

Comment: Oh, I am just going to skip your first answer, and give you the errors later. I am on the phone right. The errors have nothing to do with tkinter module... I think.

Comment: @AidanL.  That makes sense.  Ok let me know when it's convenient.

Comment: Simon, as we can see, we’ve been getting a lot of errors with cx_Freeze. And no matter how we fix it, new errors pop up. I thinking of using something else to ‘freeze’ Python scripts into an .exe file. If so, Simon, do you have any recommendations for me on freezing Python 3 into an .exe file?

Comment: @AidanL.  Ouch.  As far as I know Cx_Freeze is the only one that is still maintained.  [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html) is the only other one I know you might have a chance of getting working.

Comment: @AidanL.  You might get more luck getting an answer if you post your question as another separate question.  Someone else may be able to get it working. It seems unlikely that anyone else will read 31 comments to find your other question.  Personally I would stick with Cx_Freeze because there is the danger Pyinstaller will become obsolete and you will  be forced into Cx_Freeze anyway.  Anyway you might find alternatives.  If you do please tell me as I am not keen on Cx_Freeze either.  Another thing: I have never used Pyinstaller but I have heard it is easier and generates single files exe.

Comment: @AidanL. No problem.  I hope you solve your problem soon.

Comment: I downloaded PyInstaller, I used it to build from `.py` file into `.exe` file, but when I opened it said I am just missing one file, that is supposed to be in the build folder after the exe programs have been created, called `python36.dll`.

Comment: @AidanL.  Try copying python36.dll (located near my.exe) to the folder where the exe is located.  This might work I have never used it pyinstaller but that sounds like what they want.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that there are still more errors (the amount is about the same, when I used cx_Freeze) but I let's see if it might clear off some errors (since this error with the file seem to be the main error to everything)

Comment: @AidanL.  To help I need the trace-back.  If it's Pyinstaller my help will be limited.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it to you later. I am on my Linux (Raspberry Pi) and Windows

Comment: Simon, I had finally succeeded building python to exe. I founded out when I build the `.py` script with PyInstaller, it creates two folders: `build` and `dist`. When I run the `.exe` file in the `build` folder. Everything fails, but that is different with the `.exe` file in the `dist` folder. Everything works!. Thanks for all your help Simon!!

Comment: @AidanL.  I might go for pyinstaller myself.  Pleased I was able to help. : )

Comment: Yep, just make sure to open the ‘dist’ folder instead of the ‘build’ folder.

Comment: @AidanL.  Will do.  Thanks : )